# Using ACF or PACF to build an AR(p) model?

Tags: autocorrelation

In my text, we're told to use PACF to find the order of MA(q) models and ACF to find the order of AR(p) models. But in a homework problem, the professor specifies the order of an AR(p) model using the PACF. 
This is pretty confusing. Can anyone shed light on the apparent contradiction?

Comment: See tables in [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=gW51UqDZfB8C&pg=PA512&dq=tails+off+pacf&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EWNuU8qiKseGyAT1-YK4DQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=tails%20off%20pacf&f=false).

Comment: what text is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an MA($q$) process the theoretical auto-correlation function drops to zero after $q$ lags. For an AR($p$) process the theoretical partial auto-correlation function drops to zero after $p$ lags. The corresponding sample (partial) auto-correlation functions are often used to choose what order of MA or AR series to fit. It appears your text is in error. See e.g. the [NIST *Engineering Statistics Handbook*, §6.4.4.6](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc446.htm).